# OBIEE RPD automation from one environment to another

Tags: command-line, obiee

I'm looking at a possible script to automated the rpd deployment from one environment to another (dev,test,prod). Has anyone ever worked on such a script on a Windows based platform. There is a runbat.cmd in OBIEE, however there are no instructions on how to build the script.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can automate rpd deployments using wlst scripting language: to connect to weblogic, lock configuration, upload the new RPD, save changes and perform a system restart.
However you'll probably have to perform some aditional tasks to the RPD before uploading it, tipically, changing the connection information, because it will be different between enviroments. For that you'll need to automatically patch the RPD with the correct connection information, using XUDML files.
Here are two blogpost with examples on how to do this, you can adapt the scripts to your own needs:
http://www.askjohnobiee.com/2013/03/how-to-automatic-repository-deployment.html
http://adventuresinobiee.blogspot.co.uk/2013/02/scripted-rpd-deployments-using-udml-and.html

Regards
Ana GH